# What is the best aproach to integrate a SQL database and Firebase Firestore with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, jwt

I'm currently working in a project where we need to use a relational database and a real time solution. We decided to go with Firebase Firestore, but we are having some trouble with Firebase Authentication.

First of all, we need to save the credentials and some payment information on our SQL, and when the user logs in on our aplication, somehow we have to authenticate the user with the firebase.

One aproach that we though was to save their credentials on our sql, then create a **customToken** with **Firebase SDK**, return this token to the client and the user authenticates on firebase with this custom token, but, doing some tests, we noticed that the user can realised some unwanted actions, like self delete and alter some other datas, and this is not a good thing.

So I'am trying to came up with a solution to integrate this two guys in the system. We are using react with node.js on client side.

Comment: I think you can Trigger a Cloud Function whenever a User is Created/Deleted/Updated and with that you could make a Call to your SQL Database.

Comment: I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onDelete) on the documentation, but can I prevent that a user account could be deleted?